# Continue performing a function while Android phone is asleep?

Tags: android

I want to create an Android app which requires a function to be run every 30 seconds or so, even when the phone goes to sleep and the user isn't using it. Is this possible to do in Android with services, or do even they shut off when the phone goes to sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Simply don't do this. It will quickly drain the battery.

If you need this for a specialized function that you and only you will run, you can acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. But do not put anything on the market that actually does this! I'd consider your app malware.

An alternative to the wake lock would be using the AlarmManager to wake yourself up every n seconds. But again, if you do this every 30 seconds, or even every 5 minutes, your app is malicious.

Comment: @EboMike You should revise your answer. He didnt state the context in which his application would be use. This could be a business application used only within the confines of a specific need in which Android can full fill. You could say, You can use WAKE_LOCK but please be aware it will drain the battery fast and might be considered malware if used in a commercial setting.

Comment: I mentioned in the second paragraph that it's an option if this is a specialized application. I just want to make clear that a publicly available app should not do this.

Comment: What kind of battery drain can we expect from an app that runs a service in the background? Would it be much worse than say Google Maps in navigation mode? And would users really frown upon the app even if Conner makes it clear in the app's description / UI?

Comment: Yes, I was planning on making the function user started, with disclaimers about battery life. The concept of the app depends on the concept of doing this, it's not something I'd do without the user's permission. It basically allows the user to track their phone's sensors data every certain amount of time, the idea behind it is more concise, but in a broad way that's what it does.

Comment: @Groimx: Google in Navigation mode is an absolute battery sink. The phone runs hot when I use it! And keep in mind that the majority of users can be, let's say, simple. Unless you make it very clear in bright red letters, you'll get a lot of complaints. In any case, don't take it from me, scan the android Google groups. IIRC there's a post from Dianne that makes it very clear.

Comment: @Conner: If you make it really clear, then go ahead. The AlarmManager might be your best bet (maybe you can give the user an option to change the interval). I would recommend adding a notification while your app is running so the user is immediately aware that "battery drain mode" is active.

Comment: @EboMike I was planning on setting up two things, first was a variable duration, and I would explain the shorter the duration, the more battery is used. Plus a overall time, so how long it will record for users can set, so they don't accidentally forget it's running and get mad at there phone for losing battery so fast. Meaning it will stop recording after I certain total time.